# Unable to fire process

Tags: c#, image, process

I have application which loads images like this:

```
someImage = Image.FromFile(@"picture.png");
```

and another application which fires the previous one like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\dev\gallery.exe");
```

and if I do like this I get an Exception: "picture.png", nothing more, but if I run this first gallery application normally using the icon or cmd then it works ok.

EDIT: I have just noticed that if I put these applications in the same folder then it works properly, why? what I can do then?

Comment: What type of exception is it?  Maybe share more code?  There isn't much to go on with this description.

Comment: What type of exception? Does gallery lock the file against shared read?

Comment: Under which user are you performing the `Process.Start`? Might there be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a *working directory* problem. Try using the `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` overload with the `WorkingDirectory` property set properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but, in a different context. I used to use the command

```
Image.FromFile(@"picture.png");
```

twice in my code. Between the two commands the image was supposed to be overwritten. But, it failed. The problem was tracked to the way `Image.FromFile` works. It does not close the handle of file after reading from it.

I used an workaround posted [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/757587-image-file-release-handle) to resolve this problem.

Let me know if your issue gets resolved.

Thanks
Vamyip